# Rails cause an action to occur after set amount of time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron

I am working on an application that could be compared to an auction site.

The "auctions" have a set closing date, so my question is how does one set this auction to be "closed" when that time occurs.

For Example

Auction A:
Closes 25th December 2012 9:00am.

How do I ensure that it is "closed" at this time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd simply go with a timestamp, and methods and scopes for that.

1. Add a timestamp to your model, maybe call it `open_until`
2. define a `closed?` (and maybe `open?`) method in your model that checks the timestamp against `Time.now`
3. add a `closed` (and maybe `open`) [scope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#working-with-times) to your model. Maybe set one of them as the  `default_scope` [reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#applying-a-default-scope)

With this setup you can check on the fly if an Auction is open or closed.

```
Auction.open.all      #=> all open auctions
Auction.closed.all    #=> all closed auctions
Auction.first.closed? #=> true if 'open_until' is in the past, false otherwise
Auction.first.open?   #=> true if 'open_until' is in the future, false otherwise
```

If you use a `default_scope` (e.g. `open`), and need to find an Auction with another state (e.g. `closed)` make sure to call `Auction.unscoped.closed` [reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#removing-all-scoping).

When you need the option to close an Auction on the fly (i.e. without waiting for `open_until` to pass by) you could simply, without additional boolean flags, do this:

```
def close!
  self.update_attribute(:open_until, 1.second.ago)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If, for example, you have a `:closed` attribute on your `Auction` model you want to set to true at a certain time, you need to have a cron running to periodically run a rake task to check for new `Auction`s to close.

For example, you can create a file in `lib/tasks/close_auctions.rake` with something like the following inside

```
namespace :myapp do
  task "close-auctions" => :environment do
    Auctions.where("closes_at < ? and closed = ?", Time.zone.now, false).update_all(closed: true)
  end
end
```

This can be called via `rake` by running

```
rake myapp:close-auctions
```

You can then run this rake task on a cron in your crontab. For every minute you'd add something like this to your crontab

```
* * * * * RAILS_ENV=production rake myapp:close-auctions > /dev/null 2>&1
```

This means every minute, Rails will find any `Auction` instances that are still open but which have a `:closes_at` value that is newly in the past, marking those instances as closed.

Comment: Thanks for the great solution and explanation.
One quick question. Does the whole "* * * * * RAILS_ENV=production rake myapp:close-auctions > /dev/null 2>&1" go into a specific file to run as a cron job? Is it easier/better to use this instead http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby ?

Comment: `whenever` is just a tool to make building the commands in your crontab like the one above "simpler". `whenever` is the "middleman" between you and the crontab, so it's really not necessary as the end result is the same: a command like the one above.

Comment: As for where the command goes, as the user you deploy as you want to run `crontab -e` and an editor will open in shell for you to add the cron commands. I can't speak to how whenever or capistrano (or some other deploy tool) might integrate to make this process simpler.

Comment: After 30s research, https://github.com/javan/whenever#capistrano-integration **whenever** has support for integrating with capistrano, so that might make your life easier in terms of defining and setting the cron commands. The setup for the rake task itself remains unchanged.

Comment: Awesome, are there any known issues using this approach with Heroku, or anything that needs to be tweaked to get it to work?

Comment: Yes, actually; quite a bit. You need to install the **[Scheduler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduler)** addon for this, and the highest frequency it will run is **every 10min**. This was a huge dealbreaker for some of my apps, on top of the fact that you pay every time a dyno worker has to be spun up to run your scheduled tasks. This is one of the main reasons I moved to **[Linode](http://linode.com)**.

Comment: Accept my answer if it's answered your question please.

Comment: I have also presented a possibly simpler solution (below).